# Beautifulsoup Match Empty Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a table on a website where I am only trying to return any row where the class is blank (Row 1 and 4)

```
<tr class>Row 1</tr>
<tr class="is-oos ">Row 2</tr>
<tr class="somethingelse">Row 3</tr>
<tr class>Row 4</tr>
```

(Note there is a trailing space at the end of the `is-oos` class.

When I do `soup.findAll('tr', class_=None)` it matches all the rows. This is because Row 2 has the class `['is-oos', '']` due to the trailing space. Is there a simple way to do a `soup.findAll()` or `soup.select()` to match these rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `class_=""`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<tr class>Row 1</tr>
<tr class="is-oos ">Row 2</tr>
<tr class="somethingelse">Row 3</tr>
<tr class>Row 4</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

print(*soup.find_all('tr', class_=""))

# Or to only get the text
print( '\n'.join(t.text for t in soup.find_all('tr', class_="")) )
```

Outputs:

```
<tr class="">Row 1</tr> <tr class="">Row 4</tr>
Row 1
Row 4
```

**Edit** To only get what's in stock, we can check the attributes of the tag:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://gun.deals/search/apachesolr_search/736676037018"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).text, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all('tr'):
    if tag.attrs.get('class') == ['price-compare-table__oos-breaker', 'js-oos-breaker']:
        break
    print(tag.text.strip())
```

Comment: When I run `Beautifulsoup` on your `html_doc`, it says that Row2 only has class `is-oos` but when I run it on the response.text, from the URL, it says Row2 has class [`is-oos',''] so your code wouldn't work since it catches Row 2

Comment: @Bijan can you share the URL?

Comment: https://gun.deals/search/apachesolr_search/736676037018 is one of them. I am trying to just match if there are any in stock (`tr` where class is not `is-oos`)

Comment: Ah I see, that is clever to just break when it sees `js-oos-breaker`